# I can't handle this error in my Verilog code: "error: malformed statement"

Tags: verilog, cpu-architecture

"main.v:38: error: malformed statement". **In Adder module Call**.

I want to implement ALU in Verilog but I got this error.

Even StackOverflow's previous question couldn't help me.

```
module Adder(A, B, Cin, S, Cout);
  input A, B, Cin;
  output reg S, Cout;
  
  always @(*)
    begin
      S = (A ^ B) ^ Cin;
      Cout = (A & B) | (A & Cin) | (B & Cin);
    end
endmodule

module ALU(op1, op2, opCode, Cin, Res, cFlag, zFlag, oFlag);
  input [31 : 0] op1, op2;
  input [3 : 0] opCode;
  input Cin;
  output [31 : 0] Res;
  output cFlag, zFlag, oFlag;
  integer i;
  
  wire Cout;
  
  always @(*) begin
      if(opCode == 4'b1001) begin
        for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
           Adder adder(op1[i], op2[i], Cin, Res[i], Cout);
           case(Cout)
            1'b1 : Cin = 1'b1;
            1'b0 : Cin = 1'b0;
           endcase
        end
      end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Which line does the error message point to?

Comment: This "Adder adder(op1[i], op2[i], Cin, Res[i], Cout);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules can't be instantiated in always blocks.  Use a generate with a for loop if you need multiple instances of a module.  You could just instantiate the modules without a loop at all. I might do this with two modules at first just to get it working, then make the change to get the number (32 in this case) the design needs.

All modules are statically instantiated during the elaboration phase of simulation, one time only, and time prior to t=0.  There is no dynamic creation of modules.

You may find this helpful for this and similar issues:
https://www.amiq.com/consulting/2014/10/01/what-goes-where-in-systemverilog/
An always block is not a 'container' on this chart.